# Why do Christians in India eat meat in church?

Tags: church-local, religious-practice, diet, comparative-religion, christianity-in-india

Why do Christians in India eat non-vegetarian/meat in church, while Hindus don't eat non-vegetarian in temples?

I love Christians because they won't commit violence and they don't kill people to convert them to their religion.  But, why do they kill animals inside the temple-like church?

Comment: I'm unaware of any Christians killing animals inside a church. That would generally be considered sacrilegious, I believe.

Comment: Do Christians in India really kill animals and eat meat during their church service/worship activities?  I rather doubt that.  Perhaps you mean why do Christians eat meat in general?  ... I do understand that the eating of meat in general has historically been a stumbling block for Christianity in India, so I think that is probably what you meant to ask about.

Comment: why is this question getting up-votes if it's incomplete.

Comment: @Grasper I think the question is fine. I suspect he does not mean actually killing the animals in church. If he does, then we need a link or something because that's quite unusual.

Comment: @fredsbend, see! You don't know how he means it so don't tell me it's fine.

Comment: @Grasper There's no reason to be hostile. English is obviously not his first language. Ever heard of benefit of the doubt? How about listening to what people mean and not what they say? Be reasonable about it. Have you *ever* heard of a Christian church that kills and eats animals in the church (sounds pagan to me)? If you have then why don't you actually try helping the question by providing a link. If not, then try being more constructive than complaining about the votes it's getting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the biblical argument for eating meat, or that vegetarianism is possible but not commanded?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/17701/what-is-the-biblical-argument-for-eating-meat-or-that-vegetarianism-is-possible)

Comment: @MattGutting: If you have church in your home or other private property, and you live on a farm where you raise chickens for food, then you're naturally going to kill chickens and eat them "in church." Just because butchering animals in a western church building may seem "sacrilegious" should not in any way suggest that it should be seen that way in other cultures.

Comment: @flimzy hadn't thought of it that way. Thanks!

Comment: Eating meat in Churches in India: Yes. Killing animals in Church: I haven't seen it. Killing animals in Church outside India: Yes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_sacrifice#Christianity. The OP has to understand that "Holy place" is just a brainwashed concept. Meat does not contaminate a holy place if the people are taught that it does not. The teaching is in the Wiki page. Why are the reproductive organs (flowers) of murdered plants used inside holy places of almost all religions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There might be some confusion here, because killing animals in the church would probably not be done by most Christians.

If, however, you mean "why to Christians kill and eat animals, *in general*?" then I can answer that.

Christianity inherited its beliefs about food and animals from Judaism. Animals are perceived differently to Christians. They are not equal with humans and their lives are precious, but not as valuable as human lives. From the creation story in Genesis, Christians are taught that animals, and even *all* of Creation, is under man's dominion and stewardship. [Consider this comment below](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/42405/why-do-christians-in-india-eat-meat-in-church/42407#comment115955_42407) for some further thoughts.

Further, consuming animal meat is a large part of the culture Christians inherited from Judaism. There are Christians that advocate vegetarianism, but they are very few in number. Most Christians think that neither is a sin, to eat or not eat animal meat, so if you personally do not want to eat you do not have to, but you should also not judge what others eat. Consider [1 Corinthians 10:31 (NIV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?version=NIV&search=1%20Corinthians%2010):

> So whether you eat or drink or whatever you do, do it all for the glory of God.

Most Christians today interpret this as it being acceptable to eat or drink whatever you like so long as you glorify God when you do (i.e. avoid drunkenness and gluttony).

Reference: [What does the Bible say about vegetarian diets?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32141/what-does-the-bible-say-about-vegetarian-diets/32143#32143)

Comment: I would also add that Christians view the world differently than Hindus do: God, who is the source of Holiness, is not part of creation. Further, we believe God gave man the task of caring for the earth; and that creation itself can be used by us to fulfill that task- which would include eating animals for food. Unless I misunderstand, Hinduism allows parts of creation to be in themselves holy; thus barring their use as food. For Christians, the world is good and we must protect it; but it isn't sacred the way God is sacred. We can respectfully use it for our own good - and the world's good.

Comment: @shiningcartoonist From my understanding, you are representing Hinduism at large accurately. There is a sense  and explicit mention of pantheism in Hinduism.

Comment: "Killing animals in the church would probably not be done by most Christians." -- I expect this isn't entirely accurate. In many cultures, church buildings (if such a luxury even exists) are multi-purpose buildings, and using the same building for butchering animals as well as worship service is probably common in some places.

Answer (score 3):

I am an Indian Christian. I have spent five decades of my life in India and have never come across a church where animals are killed, either as a sacrifice or  as food for the faithful.  Of course, there are churches which accept animals and birds as offering on feasts, only to be auctioned for money.

As for the statement that Hindus do not kill animals in temples, my experience is that it should be taken with a pinch of salt. Many tribal people offer animal and bird sacrifice in their temples and even distribute the meat to the faithful as sacred food. After all, vegetarianism is not followed by all Hindus alike.

Comment: Yes, I may be wrong. Thanks for clarifying.